# Why a List of T is being replaced without calling any method or function?

Tags: list, vb.net

I'm trying to send some data to a SOAP server, so, before to send all the data I create a List (of T) but when I'm adding data the objects added change to the last events added, so, I end with a list with all the objects being the same.

Here's the code; this is the basic idea, not the whole code, I omitted all the formatting and database queries to simplify.

```
Dim xEvent As New gps.xEvent
Dim xEventList As New List(Of gps.xEvent)
xEventList.Clear()

While reader.Read()

    Timestamp = reader("timestamp").ToString()
    Patente = reader("Patente").ToString.ToUpper
    FechaHora = reader("Fecha")
    Latitud = String.Format("{0:'+'00.00000;'-'00.00000}", reader("latitude"))
    Longitud = String.Format("{0:'+'000.00000;'-'000.00000}", reader("longitude"))
    Velocidad = Convert.ToString(reader("speedKPH"))
    Sensor1 = Convert.ToString(reader("Temp1")


    xEvent.asset = Patente
    xEvent.code = xEvento
    xEvent.date = FechaHora
    xEvent.latitude = Latitud
    xEvent.longitude = Longitud
    xEvent.speed = Velocidad
    xEvent.temperature = Sensor1
    xEventList.Add(xEvent) 'When I get here the added events change to be same of the last one.
End While
```

Why is behaving like that? Is like the xEvent object is bonded to the List and I just want to add the values.
Should I create a new xEvent every time I add something to the List?

I'm using VS.NET 2022 and Framework 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the line

```
Dim xEvent As New gps.xEvent
```

into the loop. Otherwise, you're indeed adding the same reference over and over again, and since `gps.xEvent` is (presumably) a reference type, they will all contain the same data.

Comment: I didn't know that a list works with references, I thought that they add a copy. Thanks

Comment: @E_Blue In .NET that actually depends on the type of elements in the list. If you create a `List(Of integer)` that indeed creates a list of values, since integer is a value type. But for reference types (aka classes) the list only contains the reference.